# Flutter : add a circle where you click in an image

Tags: flutter, geometry, draw

(for information I'm starting on flutter)

I try to add a circle on an image when the user clicks on it, at the precise place where he clicks

I manage to display in the logs that I have clicked on the image but I cannot display a circle once I click on it

The next step is to retrieve the position where we clicked to display the circle at this location

[exemple with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8sYp.png)

```
class _Cible extends State<Cible> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text('My APP'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Circle when i clic somewhere'),
                GestureDetector(
                  
                  child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage("images/body.png"),
                      width: 280,
                      height: 450),
                
                onTap: () {
                    print("ok");
                    
                    CustomPaint(size: Size(5, 5) ,painter: CirclePainter());
                  },),
                Container(
                  child : CustomPaint(size: Size(5, 5), painter: CirclePainter())
                ),etc..

class CirclePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.teal
      ..strokeWidth = 15;

    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    canvas.drawCircle(center, 15, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use onTapUp in gesture detector :

```
onTapUp:(details) => position = details.globalposition , 
/* Same as onTap but with details parameters*/
```

Comment: I dit that : `onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) => offset = details.localPosition`, ( i print it in a method and it's good )
but i am still blocked to transmit the variable offset to my circlePainter

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a Stack rather than a Column. There's even a short video tutorial on Widget of the Week: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

You might have to also think about your Widget tree and how to make it rebuild. A quick-and-dirty way is with setState, changing `position` from null to some coordinates. And you'll need to add a widget to your stack based on position.